# Animating a text label in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to animate a text label (called label) in Swift but it isn't working. No errors, just staying put. Here's the code I have in ViewDidLoad:

```
label.text = savedText
    label.center = CGPoint(x:50, y:10)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.label.center = CGPoint(x:100, y:70)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Not really sure why it isn't working since I followed a tutorial but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share a link to the tutorial?

Comment: can you try doing the animation in `viewDidAppear` instead?

Comment: Try using label.frame instead of label.center

Comment: where are you writing this code ?

Comment: I'm writing the code inside ViewDidLoad. I tried .frame but it came up with an error. Here's the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ckl7kSwmlbY. Just realized it was Swift 1.4 so it could perhaps be the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that viewDidLoad is called before your view is visible, so the animation happens instantly.

Try adding this to your code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if label.center != CGPoint(x:50, y:10) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.label.center = CGPoint(x:100, y:70)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The if statement prevents the label from animating every time the view appears on screen, instead only doing it the first time (when the viewController is loaded initially). If you want it to happen every time just remove it.

P.s. I also removed the delay as I assumed it was an attempt to stop the bug happening (in the tutorial)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey, if this worked would you mind marking it as the correct answer and up voting it? I get points :)